# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, pointers, binary-search-tree

I wrote binary search tree by C language, which data is string, and I have problem when I tried to type data.

Error show on line 14, I think `root->data` is NULL cause it, but I don't know how to solve.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
struct Node {
    Node *parent;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
    char *data;
};
Node *insert(Node *root, char *data) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        Node *tmp;
        tmp = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        root->data = data;    // <--- Line 14
        tmp -> left = tmp -> right = NULL;
        return tmp;
    }
    if (strcmp(data, root->data) > 0) {
        root -> right = insert(root->right, data);
    } else if (strcmp(data, root->data) < 0) {
        root -> left = insert(root->left, data);
    }
    return root;
}

void Print(Node *root){
    if (root == NULL) return;
    Print(root->left);
    printf("%s\n", root->data);
    Print(root->right);
}

int main() {
    Node *root = NULL;
    char input[21];
    while (scanf("%s", input) != EOF) {
        root = insert(root, input);
    }
    Print(root);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since `root` is still null at that point, you need to set `root` to `tmp`, or — better — get rid of `tmp` and assign the result of `malloc()` to `root` instead.   Or, equivalently, change `root->data` to `tmp->data` since you currently return `tmp`.   You should also check that the `malloc()` succeeded, of course. Note that the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly; they should not be written with spaces around them. Your code doesn't set `parent`. You will need to make a copy of the string — see [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html).

Answer (score 1):

In your function:

```
Node *insert(Node *root, char *data) {
    if (root == NULL) {
        Node *tmp;            // is this really needed?
        tmp = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node)); // did your mean root = malloc(..) ?
        root->data = data;    // <--- root is always NULL, from test above

/* ... */
```